# Revert Back Android Studio 2.0 preview to Studio 1.5

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently I had updated my Android Studio 1.5 to Android Studio 2.0 Preview. Currently I'm facing lot of difficulties in Android Studio2.0 preview with regard to performance and debugging. So I want to go back to Android Studio 1.5 from Android Studio 2.0 preview.

I had changed the channel to stable channel and tried to update my studio. It shows "Already you have installed the latest version of Android studio". Is there any other way to revert back the android studio..

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: i am sure u have tried this. but unsitall and try to instal 1.5

Comment: I'm using android studio in ubuntu

Comment: you can have two workspaces one for 2.0 and one for 1.5. use 1.5 on a different path.

Comment: Nope. I'm looking to remove android studio updates....

Comment: There is now downgrading-mechanism, you will have to uninstall 2.0 -> install 1.5

Comment: please check here might can helps you http://tools.android.com/tips/using-multiple-android-studio-versions

Comment: thanks... @Stankovitch

Comment: I fixed this issue by removing all break points that were slowing down the debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way. Uninstall the android studio.
But do not forget to uncheck Android SDK before uninstallation.
When you install Android studio 1.5, then also uncheck the Android SDK. After that select the path of the previous SDK. In this way, you don't have to download SDK tools, build tools , Android SDK's again.

Answer (score 1):

There's now way you can downgrade you're IDE .. You have to uninstall it and re-install Android Studio 1.5

Link your workspace with Android Studio 1.5 and your good to go.